Discussing whole document codes
In some cases, I can not reduce questions to a MWE.
I would like to present whole and sometimes complicated codes to be discussed.
Is there a way, to do this in TexExchange?

You could try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

@mbert "1. Code must produce the desired output" -- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour

@user202729 Ah thanks for catching my bad advice

@mbert
Codereview is not specific for TeX.

@MBE In theory, as long as what you have is code instead of just document and it works it should be fine. In practice, the TeX experts are almost nonexistent in codereview.SE.

I don't think that there's necessarily anything wrong with this. For example, this question was quite well-received.

I’m voting to close this question because its proper place, paradoxically, might be meta.

why the tag "plain-tex"?

The 'M' in 'MWE' means 'enough to show the issue' - there's no specific length, so if you really cannot reduce beyond some significant portion of code, that's not a problem. You need to think about the problem you are highlighting and what is essential to show it, that's all.

a MWE is a whole document code. The needed length depends of the problem, but you should be aware that with long examples fewer people will have the time and will to check it, so it is in your interest to keep it as short and easy to compile as possible.

@Ulrike Fischer
Sometimes, a code has a lot of preconditions, that cannot be explained in detail. I try to mark the problem with comments such as "%here is the problem". In that case, I do not expect the community to review the whole code, but the marked section.

@jarnowic Just because I use PlainTex and didn't find a better tag.

As others have commented, it is possible for a MWE to be significantly long.  One big downside is that the longer your example, the less likely other people will be willing to invest the time to debug what is going on.
The other problem is that a majority of the time when someone says "here is my example", it's clear that they've not even tried to create a minimal example.  And a majority of the time when someone says "here is my minimal example", it's clear that the example is not truly minimal (although it is often almost minimal).
If userX says "here is a significant portion of code that is a minimal example of the problem", my guess would be that 49% of the time userX hasn't actually tried to create a minimal example, 49% of the time it is not truly minimal (but is close to being minimal), and rarely is actually minimal.

Sometimes, a code has a lot of preconditions, that cannot be explained in detail. I try to mark the problem with comments such as "%here is the problem". In that case, I do not expect the community to review the whole code, but the marked section.

@MBE it is very rare (the 2% that Teepeemm estimated) that all the preconditions are actually necessary to reproduce the problem. Therefore they should be removed before posting the code.

Sometimes even the answers are not a  MWE.

@MBE to the best of my knowledge, the minimal part of MWE does not apply to answers, but only questions. I'm not really sure what the criteria for being minimal would be in that case. I believe it is recommended that answers include working examples and some explanation. examples play very different roles in questions and answers, so I don't think the same criteria can be applied.

you've left out the proportion of cases where the code isn't actually an example, although I suppose that is orthogonal and should be measured as an independent dimension ....
